# how to restrict number of proposed ports by getaddrinfo

Tags: c, linux, tcp

One of my stand-alone java applications (no sources available) picks random-available port to listen on.
At this stage I assume it uses **getaddrinfo** system call to obtain addresses to bind against.

Since I'm maintaining hundreds of various servers with assigned ports, the black app sometimes kicks in and pick one of 'the assigned' ports, which cause my small servers to fail on startup...

I'm wondering is there a way to restrict number of ports proposed by the OS?
Would be mostly interested in system config solutions,
but if there are no other solutions I'm also able to hack **bind()/getaddrinfo** (this would require some hits as well ... )

thanks

Comment: I guess so, but jvm isn't OS, which eventually manages this kind of stuff.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, calling it 'random' was maybe not a best choice of mine, I think we're on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be able to control it from proc entries - For example, here is a system wide setting :

> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range

You can modify them. Or there may be [utilities](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/portreserve/) available for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If OS-wide change is not what you had in mind, configure the JVM's Java Security Manager so that `SecurityManager.CheckListen(NNN)` throws `SecurityException` for any of the port numbers you want to reserve.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec70.html

It's the solution for my problem, than I could limit port ranges